# How to install PyCharm from zip file?

Tags: python, zip, configure, pycharm, unzip

I have downloaded PyCharm and unzipped using `unzip` command.

By using help from the internet I did everything to install it, but the `./configure` command shows me an error:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Comment: is the file ./configure executable?

Comment: This is not a source distribution - please see the installation instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/Installing-Hub-with-Zip-Distribution.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install it via **snap**

- easy installation
- you get updates

https://snapcraft.io/pycharm-community